# Deleting duplicates in excel - 3 different columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have over 10,000 line items that resemble the following:

```
Company name  Contact last name  Contact first name
Bob's Company     Danny             Smith
Bob's Company     Danny             Smith
Bob's Company     Susan             Doe
Tim's Company     Danny             Doe
Tim's Company     Susan             Smith
Tim's Company     Danny             Doe
Tim's Company     Susan             Doe
```

I want to delete *exact* line duplicates, including the original.
So, I want to delete rows 1,2,4,6. Since 3,5,7 are the only originals, those would be the only ones to remain on the spreadsheet.

Comment: It's exactly for what Excel's "remove duplicates" functionality is used (it's in "data" tab). Have your tried it?

Comment: yes, and it's removing the wrong things

Comment: it's kind of strange, could you please post some screenshots?

Comment: I can't, sensitive info. I think my co-worker figured it out, somewhat. I appreciate your help!

Comment: it's deleting the duplicates, but not the original line. I need that deleted too. That's what we are struggling with.

Comment: You really have to elaborate here. The solutions proposed here normally would remove duplicates so you must have some other sort of scenario that we are unaware of.  Please provide an example where it does not work.  In your small little bit of data you showed, the methods proposed work.

Answer (score 1):

With data in columns **A** through **C** like:

[image]

In **D2** enter:

```
=A2 & CHAR(1) & B2 & CHAR(1) & C2
```

and copy down.  In **E2** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($D$1:$D$10000,D2)>1,"D","K")
```

and copy down:

[image]

Then filter on column **E** displaying all the *"D"*.

Then delete all visible rows. Then unfilter.

Comment: Tried this, it's still showing duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Before you do as "Gary's Student" sugest  - remember to delete all blank fields ALSO in company name.

Since you will no doubt have double spaces some places

```
"Bob's Company"
"Bob's Company "
"Bob's  Company"

Or 
"Danny " vs 
"Danny"
```

Comment: You are correct...........the Poster wanted to delete *exact* line duplicates...........which to me means a perfect character-by-character match.

Answer (score 0):

To extend on Gary's Student's answer, you can use conditional formatting to colorize duplicate values. Then, you can filter by color. Sometimes, this will get you directly to your goal without using any formulas. In this case, though, you do need to concatenate as already suggested.

[image]